# Lucene.Net 4.8 FSDirectory.open() terminates with System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene.net

I've realized a LuceneSearcher.cs script based on well tested examples from the internet with Lucene.Net 4.8.0-beta00016 as console application and it works like a charm.
Porting this script to an asp.net-application for the web, the command FSDirectory.open(strPath) terminates with a System.TypeInitializationException. After doing a lot of research and variations, I have no idea wheres the problem.

The line of code causing this problem:

`Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory folder = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(path);`

The result I get from the call of LuceneSearcher.cs:

```
"Message": "The type initializer for 'Lucene.Net.Diagnostics.Debugging' threw an exception.",
"StackTrace": "at Lucene.Net.Store.BaseDirectory.SetLockFactory(LockFactory lockFactory)
at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.SetLockFactory(LockFactory lockFactory)
at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory..ctor(DirectoryInfo path, LockFactory lockFactory)
at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(DirectoryInfo path, LockFactory lockFactory)
at Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(String path)
at LuceneSearcher.Search(String searchText, String[] searchFields) ...",
"ExceptionType": "System.TypeInitializationException"
```

I've tried a lot of variations and workarounds but have no success. My old LuceneSearcher.cs (v3.0.3) hasn't this problems.

If anyone has solution. Please guide me. I've been stuck for days.

Comment: Please open a bug report at https://github.com/apache/lucenenet/issues/new/choose and include the .NET version you are using as well as the operating system so we can get to the bottom of this. It would be preferable if you could include an example repro project as well as the LuceneSearcher.cs code.